# Stop event propagation in Bonsai.js

Tags: javascript, events, bonsaijs

How do I stop a `mousedown` event from propagating to the stage?

```
stage.addListener("pointerdown", startDrawing);

rect = Path.rect(x, y, 100, 100);
stage.addChild rect;

rect.addListener("pointerdown", selectHandler);
```

`startDrawing` gets called each time after `selectHandler`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Curiously though, I had the answer to the question all along, was just tricked into thinking it wasn't working.*

Stop the event in the selectHandler:

```
function selectHandler(e) {
  e.stop();
};
```

P.S You can see my work in progress here: http://codepen.io/zinkkrysty/pen/iyrjG?editors=001